# FPDF - error: Image file name is empty al colocar ruta por medio de variable

Tags: php, imagen, fpdf, headers

Tengo este problema, necesito poner la imagen en el header pero con una variable:
$this->Image($logo,11,12,33,0);
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado varias maneras, por ejemplo estas:
$this->Image('$logo',11,12,33,0);

$this->Image("$logo",11,12,33,0);

$this->Image(.'$logo'.,11,12,33,0);

$this->Image($row['logo'],11,12,33,0);

pero sale este error
(error: Image file name is empty')

Cabe resaltar que si uso la ruta de forma manual, el error no se presenta:
$this->Image('../images/medilaser.png',11,12,33,0,'png');
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero necesito que me postule el logo según la empresa a la que pertenece el usuario.

He hecho var_dumpl y me muestra que la varible si contiene la ruta correcta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código como texto, no como imágenes. No todos pueden verlas y además no podemos copiar tu código así.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no encontré una mejor opción, dejo la forma en que lo pude resolver, no es la mejor manera, pero funciona como lo necesito, tuve que hacer un if por cada empresa de esta manera:

```
"if ($empresa == "MEDILASER S.A.S.") {
    class PDF extends FPDF
    {
    // Cabecera de página
    function Header()
    {
        // Logo
        $this->Image('../images/medilaser.png',11,12,33,0,'png');
        // Arial bold 15
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
        // Movernos a la derecha
        $this->Cell(40,16,'',1);
        // Título
        $this->Cell(100,16,utf8_decode('FICHA TÉCNICA PRESTACIÓN DE SERVICIOS DE SALUD'),1,0,'C');

        $this->Cell(25,4,utf8_decode('VERSIÓN'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,4,utf8_decode('11'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(4);
        $this->SetX(147);
        $this->Cell(25,4,utf8_decode('VIGENCIA'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,4,utf8_decode('MARZO 2022'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(4);
        $this->SetX(147);
        $this->Cell(25,4,utf8_decode('CÓDIGO'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,4,utf8_decode('F-GJ-145 MD'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(4);
        $this->SetX(147);
        $this->Cell(25,4,utf8_decode('PÁGINAS'),1,0,'C');
        $this->Cell(0,4,'{nb}',1,0,'C');
        $this->Ln(4);
    }
    // Pie de página
    function Footer()
    {
        // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Número de página
        $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Página ').$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }}}"
```